# Which interface do I have to implement for an item collection

Tags: c#, collections, interface

```
Class: Episode with properties string name, uint orderNumber and timespan length.
Class: TVserie with episodes[] property.
```

How do I make something like this:

```
TVseries breakingBad = new TVseries();
breakingBad.episodes.add(511, "Confessions", 30.00);
```

Which Interface provides the 'add' and other collection functionality to my custom classes?

==============================

Edit: thanks! I changed it to:

```
List<Episode> breakingBadSeason5 = new List<Episode>();
Episode episode = new Episode();
episode.Name = "confessions";
breakingBadSeason5.Add(episode);
```

Comment: 1) `add` should be uppercase 2) See [`ICollection<T>.Add` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63ywd54z.aspx) on MSDN

Comment: `uint` is not in the CLS; use `int` or `long`. Or consider using a string for an order number. It's not like you're going to be doing math on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want an `Episodes[]` property - since arrays are non resizable.

Use a `List<Episodes>` instead. Then you can add all you like.

To answer your question however, the interface is [`ICollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63ywd54z.aspx)

Full answer:

```
public class TVSerie
{
public List<Episode> Episodes{get;set;}

public TVSerie ()
{
   this.Episodes = new List<Episode>
}

}
```

---

```
TVserie breakingBad = new TVserie();
Episode episode = new Episode();
episode.Foo = "Foo";
episode.Bar = "Bar";
breakingBad.Episodes.Add(episode);
```

Comment: Arrays are *not resizable* is I think what you meant to say.

Comment: Your link is to `IList<T>`, not to `ICollection`, and I think you meant `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: Ah, SO filtered out the triangular brackets because they look like html markup. Better now.